# Custom Metadata Manipulation in APEX

Tags: custom-metadata

I am attempting to do some DML on a Custom Meta Data record, to allow users to have some "Defaults" when a managed package is installed, that we would also like them to be able to manipulate (and save via APEX).

However, I am receiving errors when I attempt to perform DML operations in Apex:

```
Default_Property_Mapping__mdt mapping = new Default_Property_Mapping__mdt();
mapping.Field_Name_c = 'test';
mapping.SFDC_Object_Name__c = 'Contact';
insert mapping;
```

The meta data type *Visibility* is set to **Public** and the *Field Malleability* is set to **Subscriber Editable**, however, I am thinking that [the guide](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/210/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/custom_metadata_types_impl_guide.pdf) is ambiguous on this point that this does not make these "records" editable in ***APEX***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Apex code can create, read, and update (but not delete) custom
>   metadata records, as long as the metadata is subscriber-controlled and
>   visible from within the code's namespace. **DML operations aren’t
>   allowed on custom metadata in the Partner or Enterprise APIs**. With
>   unpackaged metadata, both developer-controlled and
>   subscriber-controlled access behave the same: like
>   subscriber-controlled access.

Please refer for more details on [custom meta-data](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custommetadatatypes_accessing.htm&type=5)